# Using Directive to declare a pseudo-type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, using, using-directives

I inherited some source code that I am just starting to dig though, and i found the previous owner has made some use of the `using` directive as an alias for a `List<T>`, but I've never seen this specific approach before.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using pType1 = List<type1>;
    using pType2 = List<List<type1>>;

     // classes here
}
```

Both of these elements are used quite heavily within the code and are also return types from several of the key methods within the code.  I get what he was trying to accomplish with using a simple name rather than repeating `List<type1>` and `List<List<type1>>` over and over again.  I'm debating whether to create a real type to replace the using statements, but before i spend the time, I was wondering if there were any pros/cons to keeping the current implementation.

Comment: It is indeed rare to see those usages. It's in code bases where authors usually are trying to hide their lack of understanding where generics are useful. I have seen things like `List<Dictionary<List<type1>, IEnumerable<Foo>>>` :-) Even if you give this beast a name it is still a beast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, if a data structure represents some entity in your application's domain model it should get its own type; it makes the code much clearer and understandable. On the other hand, if you just need a `List<List<string>>` for intermediate data processing there's no real benefit in making a proper type for that.

In your case, since the original dev went to the trouble of making an alias for the type it's logical that it would be used a lot, which points to the "represents an entity" scenario. If so, definitely go ahead and create a new type for the structure (possibly something more appropriate than bare lists and usually something defined in terms of interfaces rather than concrete classes, but that depends on what you 're actually modelling there).

Comment: Thanks Jon... your answer was me the "best" con for keeping the current structure.  I am going to implement my own types.  Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

If that construct is used as heavily as you say, I would definitely replace it with (the) real types (explicitly write out the List or create a new type). If someone happens to change one of the type declarations, like

```
using pType1 = List<type2WhichType1InheritsFrom>;
```

because (s)he thinks the base version does something better without looking at all places where it is used, there might be some unwanted side effects.

Comment: Agree with you in practice but in theory if Liskov's Substitution is abided by it should not cause an issue

Comment: With changing authors vanishes the knowledge about specific implementation details. Said this, I do always try to make my code as maintainable as possible. We had some projects where the original authors left the company and gave us some very interesting code constructs only to ensure modifying one line would break the entire application... I hate practive vs. theory :-)

Comment: @DanielElliott Isn't this going in the other direction?  If I have a List<object>, I can only change it to a List<string> if there is no place where a non-string object is added to the list.